# Circular Locations

Tags: math, processing

I am trying to draw some ellipses like if they were in the perimeter of an imaginary circle.I have done my logic, I do not see where it fails. Basically what I do is move the starting point where I want, then get locations using trigonometry, given that the angle and the hypotenuse are kwown. See the code:

```
 // Curve for 5 number
translate(width/6*3-30, width/6*4);
for(int alpha = 0; alpha < 120; alpha = alpha +5){

  int radius = (int)random(30)+20;
  int xpos = (int)cos(alpha)*350; int ypos= (int)sin(alpha)*350;

  ellipse(xpos,ypos,radius,radius);}
```

}

Comment: What is happening, and what are you expecting to happen?  What is 350?

Comment: @Teepeemm 350 looks like radius of the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cos()` and `sin()` are expecting radians. Try `sin(radians(alpha))`

Also perhaps you should make xpos and ypos floats...